# Nodes cannot pull image from docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vps

I followed [hobby-kube/guide](https://github.com/hobby-kube/guide) how to set up your own cluster, but I stuck. I created an issue on repo as well but maybe here would me more people to help me with it.

I am trying to set up my cluster on Scaleway. I follow instructions one by one, and I am at the point where I installed wave as CNI, and I've got:

```
kube-system   weave-net-dtwbj                2/2     Running                 1          9d
kube-system   weave-net-kmxq7                0/2     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          9d
kube-system   weave-net-pzfcj                0/2     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          9d
```

So my issue is on my nodes but not on master.

I found [suggestions in one of issues](https://github.com/hobby-kube/guide/issues/74) and this time I applied these suggestions, but the output is the same.

#### UFW / Firewall

I skip the part with firewall, on every VPS I've got:

```
> ufw status
Status: inactive
```

In scaleway config all my VPS have the same security policy applied. Only outbound traffic on ports `[25, 465, 587]` is dropping.

#### Internet connection

On both my nodes I've issue to download images from docker's registry and I believe that this is the real issue here

```
> docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

On master hello-world was pulled successfully.

Nodes have internet connection outside:

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 8011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.008/1.139/1.258/0.073 ms
```

#### WireGuard

By the output of `wg show` I assume that VPN between my VPS is set up correctly

```
peer: 3
  endpoint: 3-priv IP:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.1.3/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 17 seconds ago
  transfer: 7.50 GiB received, 6.50 GiB sent

peer: 2
  endpoint: 2-priv IP:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.1.2/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 41 seconds ago
  transfer: 4.96 GiB received, 6.11 GiB sent
```

Could anybody help me track the issue down and help me to fix it? I can provide any kinds of logs you wish just tell me how I can get it

Comment: try to ping registry-1.docker.io and make it's accessible, also it looks like you are using hub (registry) from docker.io, make sure it's configured properly in your hub.docker.com account.

Comment: In some cases adding the google dns server (nameserver 8.8.8.8) in your `/etc/resolv.conf`. Can you have a look and try if this works?

Comment: Hey guys, @thomas I tried to change it, but it didn't help still same error. @oleg if I ping `registry-1.docker.io` I've got `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0`, every docker command end up with `Client.Timeout` - same as from my question. Even docker login. Do you guys have any ideas how I can find root cause of my issue?